# Inconsistent selection behavior on tabbing into mat-input

Tags: angular, angular-material

Im using a set of Material mat-input controls, and I can't quite understand the selection logic when the user arrives in the control.  In some cases, I get the entire value of the field selected, in other cases the cursor is positioned for at the to the left of the existing input.

See examples below:

Ex 1 cursor is positioned after last character of pre-existing value:
[image]

Ex 2 - whole value is selected..
[image]

How do I control this behavior?  If the is a prexisting value in the input field, I'd like the whole thing selected so if the user wants to change it, they can just start typing.

Here's the html for input element:

```
<mat-form-field class="input-cell" [ngClass]='inputClass'
   *ngIf="rowFocus && (inputType==InputTypeEnum.textInput  || inputType==InputTypeEnum.numberInput || inputType==InputTypeEnum.percentInput)">

   <mat-label>{{fieldName}}</mat-label>

   <input matInput placeHolder="placeholder" [(ngModel)]="value" (focus)="gotFocus()" (click)="inputClick($event)"
   [disabled]="readOnly"
      (blur)="lostFocus($event)" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" #cellInput
      (keydown)="keyDown($event)"
       >
   <mat-error>{{errorText}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I think that if the input element is getting focus when the page first loads, then the cursor is positioned but the value is not selected. When tabbing back and forth between input elements, the values are selected, and the user can start typing and overwrite the existing value. Obviously it also depends on what you are doing in `getFocus` method.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by calling select on the HTMLElement in teh focus event with a delay, as follows:

Added to the component:

```
 @ViewChild('cellInput') inputElement: ElementRef; //refers to the input element

 gotFocus() {
  setTimeout(()=>{ this.inputElement.nativeElement.select();},100)
 }
```